# ROS Answers SE migration: pr2_teleop

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi
Where can I find the pr2_teleop package to download/install?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60449/pr2_teleop/) by [agrirobot-George](https://answers.ros.org/users/3227/agrirobot-george/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-04-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you seen this link ? http://ros.org/wiki/pr2_teleop. You may be better off installing pr2_apps package (http://ros.org/wiki/pr2_apps). Just curious, which version of ROS are you using ?

---

Originally posted by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) with karma: 1108 on 2013-04-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [agrirobot-George](https://answers.ros.org/users/3227/agrirobot-george/) on 2013-04-11**:
I am using ros electric. how do I install the pr2_apps? I tried using sudo apt-get install ros-electric-pr2_apps however I get error messages like something wicked happenned resolving 'http://security.ubuntu.com:http' (-5- No address associated with hostname

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2013-04-11**:
@agrirobot-George Try sudo apt-get install ros-electric-pr2-apps, I would hope that works ! I am on Fuerte, so cannot confirm about Electric with certainity. ** UPDATE ** == > It works on Fuerte, should work just fine on Electric.

**Comment by [agrirobot-George](https://answers.ros.org/users/3227/agrirobot-george/) on 2013-04-11**:
I did but I get error messages like thiswicked happenned resolving 'http://security.ubuntu.com:http' (-5- No address associated with hostname

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2013-04-11**:
@agrirobot-George Have you set up your ROS repositories ? this may be some corruption, you may need to reset your ROS repositories. The repository and the package (pr2_apps) works fine !

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2013-04-11**:
I am also facing this 'wicked' thingy == > delete and reset the repos !